# Why RBP instead of another register as a frame pointer?

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, x86-64, stack-frame

I understand the usage of `push rbp`...`pop rbp` at the start and end of a function to preserve the `rbp` value of the calling function, since the `rbp` register is callee-preserved. And then I understand the 'convention' of using `rbp` as the current top of the stack frame for the current procedure being executed. But related to this I have two questions:

1. Is `rbp` just a convention? Could I just as easily use `r11` (or any other register or even 8 bytes on the stack) as the base of the stack frame? Is there anything special about the `rbp` register, or it's just used as the stack frame based upon history and convention?
2. Why is `mov %rbp, %rsp` used as a 'cleanup' method before leaving a function? For example, often the `push/pop` instructions will be symmetrical, so is the `mov %rbp, %rsp` just a shorthand way where someone can 'skip' doing the symmetrical pops/adds and such? What would be an actual usage of where `mov %rbp, %rsp` would be useful? Almost all the times I see it in compiler output (with zero optimizations turned on), it seems either unnecessary or redundant, and I'm having trouble thinking of a scenario where it might actually be useful.

Comment: 1) You don't even need a frame pointer. You can address relative to `rsp`. You could not address relative to `sp` in 16 bit mode. 2) Actual usage is if you do dynamic stack allocation, e.g. via `alloca`, or, as you say, skip balancing the stack at each step.

Comment: Have you tried looking at compiler output to see what they actually do?  https://godbolt.org/.  They don't use `mov %rbp, %rsp` or `leave` when it would be redundant (just `pop %rbp`), even with un-optimized code (or `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` in general.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optimized code doesn't use frame pointers at all, except for stuff like VLAs / `alloca` (variable-sized movement of RSP), or if you specifically use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` (e.g. to make `perf record` stack sampling more efficient/reliable).  Un-optimized code is usually not as interesting to look at. [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

- [x86_64 : is stack frame pointer almost useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417784/x86-64-is-stack-frame-pointer-almost-useless)
- [Why is it better to use the ebp than the esp register to locate parameters on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346690/why-is-it-better-to-use-the-ebp-than-the-esp-register-to-locate-parameters-on-th) (only for code-size)
- [What are the advantages of a frame pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797915/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-frame-pointer)

So there are plenty of duplicates for the part about when / why to use a frame pointer at all.  The interesting part is whether a register other than RBP could have been chosen.

---

**The only things special about RBP** are that [`leave`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/leave) can compactly do RSP=RBP + pop RBP; and that a `(%rbp)` [addressing mode requires an explicit `disp8` or `disp32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base) (with value 0).

**So *if* you are going to use a frame pointer at all, you should pick RBP because it's at least as good as any other reg at being a frame pointer, but worse than other regs for some other uses.**  You never need `0(frame_pointer)`, only other offsets.  (R13 has the same always-needs-a-disp8=0 effect, but then every stack access would always need a REX prefix, like for `add -12(%r13), %eax` which doesn't with RBP.)

Also, all other "legacy" registers (that you can use without a REX, i.e. not R8-R15) have at least one implicit use in [at least one instruction that compilers may actually generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529449/why-are-rbp-and-rsp-called-general-purpose-registers), like `cmpxchg16b`, `cpuid`, `shl %cl, %reg`, `rep movsb` or whatever, so any other reg would be worse as a frame pointer.  You can't do simple naive un-optimized (or toy-compiler) code-gen if you need to shuffle things around to free up RBX for some instruction that needs it for a different purpose.  (Stack unwinding on exceptions may also rely on the frame pointer *always* being in a specific register, if your `.cfi_*` directives specified that.)

Consistency with previous x86 modes would have been sufficient reason to use RBP, to make it easier for puny human minds to remember, but there are still code-size and other reasons to pick RBP if you're going to use one.  (In fact, since `(%rsp)` addressing modes always need a SIB byte, the instructions to set up a frame pointer can actually pay for themselves over a large function in terms of code size, although not in instructions / uops.)

---

**Reasons that aren't still relevant:**

An RBP base address implies the SS segment, like RSP, which was relevant in 16-bit mode, and theoretically in 32 (where non-flat memory models were possible), but not in 64-bit mode where it only affects the exception you get from a non-canonical address.  So that part of the reason is basically gone, pretty much nobody cares about `#GP` vs. `#SS` there.

`enter` is too slow to be usable, but `leave` is still worth using if RSP isn't already pointing at the saved RBP, only costing 1 extra uop vs. manual `mov %rbp, %rsp` / `pop %rbp` on Intel CPUs, so that's what GCC does.  You claim to have seen useless `mov %rbp, %rsp` instructions, but that's not what compilers actually do.

**Note that `mov %rbp, %rsp` (3 bytes) is smaller than `add $imm8, %rsp` (4 bytes)**, so if you're using a frame pointer, you might as well restore RSP that way if it's not pointing at the saved RBP.  (Unless you need to restore other registers if you saved them right below RBP instead of after a `sub $imm, %rsp`, although you can do the restoring with `mov` loads instead of pop.)

Comment: what about recursion? Does recursion have any unique requirements/advantages of using a frame pointer?

Comment: @carl.hiass: No, it doesn't, it's just a function call to a function that also has to work when called by functions that aren't itself.  If it's proper recursion, you don't have any variables that are shared between invocations in the chain of recursive calls, only interaction via function args and return value(s).  It is asm so you're not limited to only one return-value register.

Comment: @carl.hiass: You could imagine some "private" recursive function that's only ever called from itself or a public wrapper function, and in that case many you have only the public function set up a frame pointer.  So you can have some shared state in stack memory instead of in registers that have to get saved/restored and copied around every call.  But you can still use recursion as a stack e.g. for traversing a tree.  This is exactly equivalent to taking a pointer arg to a state struct, in fact *is* that with a custom calling convention where that arg register is call-preserved.

Comment: #SS is not the only consequence of implicitely referencing the stack, even in 64 bit mode.  For instance, operand size (generally) defaults to 8 bytes, without need for REX.

Comment: @l.k: I'm talking about *explicit* reference to the stack, like `mov eax, [rbp-4]` or `mov eax, [rsp+4]`.  That's the relevant issue with using a frame pointer or not for referencing local vars.  You can sometimes use `push` to init local vars at the same time you reserve space for them, if you need the value in memory ([although compilers fail to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485395)). And yes 64-bit is the default operand-size for `push`, but you generally wouldn't use push/pop for access to your own stack frame after the function prologue.